# UWP File Picker Contract / Provider

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I'm looking for a point in the right direction. We're thinking of building an app in our office, and one of the features we're looking at is to be able to open and save files from our app in other apps and applications.
We came across the File Picker Contract which, with some simple examples, seems to be what we're looking for. But the one thing missing is it only seems to be available in other Universal apps (but it doesn't seem all of them).

Using multiple examples, we were able to see our apps in our other apps, but I'm hoping to take it further. For example, I thought Office 2016 was a Universal app, so shouldn't File Picker Contract apps appear in there as well? And is there a way to add it globally to all File Open / Save Pickers (like from notepad, or the snipping tool)?

This MSDN page ([article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186456.aspx)) seems to suggest the picker uses a single, unified interface. Shouldn't that be the same interface the rest of the operating system uses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support Classic Windows apps, filepickercontract is not a right solution. It's only applicable for 'modern'... Win8.1 store or Win10 UWP apps.
And, current office2016(for desktop) is not an UWP app, I believe. UWP ver of Office 2016 is only applicable for Win10 Mobile.

One alternative is make a shell extension. By using this, you can extend the explorer's shell space and add your own items to explorer tree. But shell extension is so complex, old and only applicable for desktop devicefamily. I don't think that now is a nice timing to implement it.

I hope this answer could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took another look at office 2016, and I believe you're correct. Only the mobile version is UWP. (I noticed Office 2016 Desktop allows for AddIns, and as far as I can tell UWP apps don't allow for those yet. It is another feature that our internal app will be losing if we go to UWP. Though, with Edge getting addins in 2016, this may be coming).

Comment: For the alternatives, I had looked into Shell Extensions a while back. I was hoping Windows 10 would have removed the need for them. We found a shell extension was too much work through the development to the deploy process. Another alternative we're working with is WebDav. It is also an aging technology, and doesn't give us nearly the same features as the File Picker Contract would. I hate to think these are the only alternatives in Windows 10 to integrate with all File Pickers.